# Error: The Java EE server classpath is not correctly set up

Tags: jenkins, ant, classpath

I am trying to create `.war` file using cmd: `ant.bat -file build.xml`
even getting same error in Jenkins also.

[image]

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2.

Comment: please post your build.xml file.